# Am I computing $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I decided to do some limits for fun, and after a while I came up with this limit$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$$which I thought that I might be able to compute. Here is my attempt at doing so:

If we take the limit as $x\to0$ on the $y$-axis (as $y=0$), we get$$L\overset{\text{along the }y\text{-axis}}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2}x=\lim_{x\to0}x=0$$and doing the same thing along the $x$-axis (as $x=0$) gets us$$L\overset{\text{along the }x\text{-axis}}=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y^2}{-y}=\lim_{y\to0}-y=0$$however, just to make sure, I decided to check with Wolfram Alpha, which told me that the [limit does not exist](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2BPower%5By%2C2%5D%2Cx-y%5D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%7D-%3E%7B0%2C0%7D%5D), although when I compute the limit in Wolfram Cloud, it seems to be correct:

[image]

So my question is: Am I computing $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$ correctly, or does it really not exist?

Comment: no, you can't conclude that the limit is $0$ considering only two paths

Comment: @SineoftheTime Wait what paths did I miss?

Comment: @CrSb0001 infinite paths

Comment: The limit exists if and only if the limit along *every possible* path exists.  This includes the axes, straight lines through the origin (consider the line $y=x$), curvy lines, spirals, and anything else you can imagine.  The value of considering limits along paths is not that it is a good tool for showing that a limit exists, but that it is a good tool for showing that a limit *does not* exist.

Comment: @XanderHenderson in this particular example, considering path along $y = x$ doesn't make sense, since it's not in the domain of function, but, that doesn't stop us from considering some path to which $y=x$ is tangent, like $y = \sin x$.

Comment: @Ennar I wasn't really thinking about this example specifically, just pointing out another line to consider.  I try not to answer questions in the comments.  And there is no reason to go to anything as scary as the sine function for a counter-example.  Pick any two random lines through the origin.  With probability 1, the limit along those lines will differ.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Good point, but for all other straight lines through the origin, the limit remains 0. Better choose something like a parabola with a quadratic term of $x$, as done in my answer below. That will complete the proof.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Sure sure.  Again, the basic point is that you can't just check a finite number of curves.

Comment: You can try `Limit[(x^2+y^2)/(x-y),{x,y}->{0,0}]` in Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. That is because you must show that no matter which direction you approach the point (0,0) from, you will always obtain the same limit- which is not true. You have only shown that the limit is same for two select paths, not the infinitely many possible paths, for which you will have to use the epsilon delta definition of a limit for a multivariate function.

Note that there are infinitely many paths you can choose from to approach (0,0). Apart from straight lines through (0,0), you can approach along basically any curve that includes the origin.

Consider if you approach along the curve $y = x - 3x^2$. Clearly, this is a valid path to approach, since the point (0,0) lies on it. Computing the limit along this particular path, we obtain that the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$, which confirms that indeed a limit does not exist.

Comment: Isn’t your lim $2/3$ rather than $1/3$?

Comment: @Aig Thanks for pointing that out